# Usage of the word "you"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a novel.  I want to write an accusatory interjection e.g., "You rascal."  My grammar checker rejects this.  My whole life I have heard people making accusations this way.  Is it incorrect grammar?

Comment: The best even a really good grammar checker can do is *suggest* that a passage you've written *might* be wrong.

Comment: It is a fragment -- it can be grammatical in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It's informal and almost always used in speech (or representations thereof), but it's certainly grammatical since you'll find the definition in dictionaries:

> Used in exclamations to address one or more people.
>   *‘you fools’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/you)</sub>

A notable example would be in Dickens:

> ‘Oh you beauties!’ cried Susan Nipper, affecting to salute the door by which the two ladies had departed.
>   <sub>[Dombey and Son](https://books.google.com/books?id=HeDDCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq="%E2%80%98Oh+you+beauties!%E2%80%99+cried+Susan+Nipper".)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To form a complete sentence, it requires a verb so “you *are* fools” is a grammatical sentence. However, an interjection like this (e.g., “wow”, “fun”, “oh no”) is acceptable in everyday conversation. An automated grammar checking program may still flag it as an incomplete sentence if it rigidly adheres to requiring a verb in every sentence.